# Using Poincaré lemma to find the generator $H^1$ of $\mathbb R^2 -\{(0,0)\}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am working towards an undertanding of de Rham cohomology. For this reason I am trying to find generator(s) of $H^n_{dR}(\mathbb R^2 -\{(0,0)\})$ and currently I am working on the case $n=1$. I believe I should use the Poincaré lemma for this. Let me give its statement here:

If $X$ is a contractible open subset of $R^n$, any smooth closed $p$-form $\alpha$ defined on $X$ is exact, for any integer $p > 0$.

What's not clear to me is how I can apply it even though $\mathbb R^2 -\{(0,0)\}$ is not contractible. Please could somebody help me with this?

I calculated the (co-)homology groups using cellular homology.

Comment: The Poincare lemma alone isn't sufficient. Do you know, e.g., the Mayer-Vietoris sequence?

Comment: @MikeMiller I'm sorry I just realised that maybe I asked something slightly different from what I actually wanted to ask. Let me edit the question...

Comment: @astudent sorry I was not clear in my comment in the previous question.  I did not mean to imply that you would need the poincare lemma to work out $H^1$ of this space, just that that would be a nice order to learn things in.

Comment: @StevenGubkin I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

For a closed 1-form $\omega$, define $f: Z^1(M)\rightarrow R,\ f(\omega)=\oint_C \omega$ along the unit circle $C$ in $M=\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$. Exact forms are obviously in the kernel of the map since $\oint_C dg=g(1,0)-g(1,0)=0$. On the other side if $f(\omega)=0$ then the integral $g(p)=\int_{(1,0)}^p\omega$ is path independent thus it defines smooth function $g$ and $\omega=dg$ is exact.
So $H_{DR}^1(M)=Z^1(M)/d\Omega^0(M)=Z^1(M)/\ker(f)=\operatorname{img}(f)=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear: which part of your answer talks about the generators and which about the Poincaré lemma?

Comment: @astudent: From the answer one sees that any closed 1 form $\omega$ which satisfies $\int_C\omega \neq 0$ serves as a generator. Poincare lemma is not used.

Comment: The last step is that we need to see there is a $1$-form not in the kernel.  This comes down to a computation:  see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/975411/34287

Comment: Although MikeMiller does have a point that you could also compute this using the poincare lemma, H^0 of a space with two connected components, and Mayer-Vietoris.

Comment: Right $\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}$ is a generator, this could be verified directly, or be computed from $d\theta$ (the polar coordiantes) or the imaginary part of $dz/z$ (where z=x+iy), since $\oint d\theta=2\pi$ and $\oint dz/z=2\pi i$.